# C# ASP.NET, ADFS Where to set up the passive endpoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, adfs

I try to communicate with an `ADFS` Server from an ASP.NET Project.
The certificates and federation have been set up but when a user is authenticated on the `ADFS` the server returns this error :

> The WSFederationPassiveEndpoint address is not configured on the relying party trust identified by the endpoint 'https://xxxxxxx.com/'. It is required to process the current request.

Unfortunately I couldn't find where to set this up.
The Microsoft's documentation does not mention this URL.

Is this a specific parameter in the `ADFS` server or is it actually a configuration to be done on my application?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look in the ADFS wizard on the server.

Under the RP, click "Endpoints" and then add the required WS-Fed one.